# MVC Pattern Clarification

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Just I started learning MVC pattern, of course i am learning it from Microsoft's website.Just i want to gather quiz information from the experts.

My understanding is (correct me then and there)

1 ) MVC does not support server side events, but supports client side events. If it supports client side events, I need html page with jQuery/Javascript (view), but most of the example I absorbed is to display the information(model) in view, I did not see any client side event handling happens in view.

2) Except ViewState and controlState, MVC supports Sessions, Application State management, Cache management.

3) When request goes to MVC engine, the routing module routes the request that is picked up by the controller. The controller in executes the appropriate action and returns the appropriate view.

Comment: @dinah Correct me if I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> MVC does not support server side events ,but supports client side events.

Client-side events have nothing to do with the server technology, be it WebForms, MVC or whatever. It's just JavaScript which can perform some actions when processing element events. For example, it may issue a request to some Url. But at the server side, nobody will care about who sent the request, the browser or the asynchronous JavaScript. It'll just process the request. That is why you don't see any event processing on the server.

> Except ViewState and controlState,MVC supports Sessions,Application State management,Cache management.

MVC does not support ViewStates or ControlStates. If you wish persistence between requests, you need to implement them from scratch.

> When request goes to MVC engine ,the routing module routes the request that is picked up by the controller.The controller in executes the appropriate action and return the appropriate view.

Correct. Except for the requests for files physically available on server are intercepted by IIS and served directly. A request for `mysite.com/images/picture.png` would not enter the pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

1. MVC does away with the traditional ASP.NET model of "web controls" which act like controls on a windows form.  There are no "events" on the client side, other than the normal events presented by the [HTML Document Object Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model)l, which exists outside the purview of ASP.NET.  DOM events are implemented by the browser manufacturer and may be consumed by [javascript](http://jquery.com).  You can also use [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) to access a controller method on the server, but this is just a background request and not an event.
2. This is correct.
3. That is correct as well.